# Vertical scroll bar does not appear when the gridview items exceeded the display height

Tags: wpf, gridview, listview, scrollviewer

I place the following statements in the second row of my grid in the xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
     <ListView Name="listView" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DateTime}" Header="Date Time" Width="140"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Vehicle}" Header="Vehicle" Width="130"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AlarmType}" Header="Alarm Type" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Direction}" Header="Direction" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Speed}" Header="Speed" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Alarmed}" Header="Alarmed" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LoadType}" Header="Load Type" Width="100"/>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="Status" Width="110"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>     
        </ScrollViewer>
 </Grid>
```

I binded the listView.ItemSource to an ObservableCollection defined in the code to populate data to the list.  When the number of items added to the GridView exceeded the listview height, the vertical scroll bar did not appear as i specified in the XAML.  What did I do wrong?  Your input is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It works for me:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListView Name="listView" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1">

                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=.}" Header="Whatever" Width="140"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, the `ListView` control template contains a `ScrollViewer` already such that the `ScrollViewer` will appear *inside* the `ListView` as and when needed. Why do you need to wrap it in another?

Comment: Thanks Kent, i deleleted one un-used column in my listview and the scroll bar showned (without the 2nd wrapping scrollviewer).

Answer (score 3):

See that the margins and paddings are correct. The scrollbar can be behind something.

Put the exterior container height with a fixed value, It can be *stretching* the listview so it will never show the  scrollbar.

HTH

Comment: Thanks Artur.  Your suspection was corrected.  I got it to work now.

Comment: What should I do when I don't know the height of the window/container at design time? My window can be maximized and resized for example, so how can I apply your solution even without knowing the dynamic height my window/container will have at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
listView.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the MaxHeight property to constraint your listview to a specific height and the scrollbar will appear automaticly.
For example :

```
 <ListView Name="listView" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" MaxHeight="300">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DateTime}" Header="Date Time" Width="140"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Vehicle}" Header="Vehicle" Width="130"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AlarmType}" Header="Alarm Type" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Direction}" Header="Direction" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Speed}" Header="Speed" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Alarmed}" Header="Alarmed" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LoadType}" Header="Load Type" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="Status" Width="110"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of using `ScrollViewer`. Just remove the `ScrollViewer` and use only the `ListView` and try.

```
ListView listView = new ListView();
listView.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
listView.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
MainGrid.Children.Add(listView);
```

No need of specifying the width and height for the listview.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid x:Name="MainMenuButtonGrid">
  <StackPanel Margin="50,0,0,0">
    <TextBlock Text="Please select any employee" Foreground="Wheat"/>
    <ListView x:Name="listEmployeeDetail" SelectedValuePath="EmployeeID">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn Header="EmployeeName" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding EmployeeName}"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```